# Enable pretty printing by default in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, pretty-print

How do I enable pretty printing by default in IPython? I haven't been able to find clear instructions anywhere on how to do this.
Thanks much!

Comment: It's enabled by default in ubuntu. What are you using?

Comment: This [forum thread](http://grokbase.com/t/scipy.org/ipython-user/12b9kbt2kv/pretty-print-as-default-print-function) had the same issue as you. I would check it out!

Comment: Do you just want the `Out [123]:` lines in IPython to do the equivalent of `pprint.pprint(_)` instead of `print(repr(_))`, or do you want to hook every call to `print` to `pprint.pprint` instead, or something like that?

Comment: Or… if you just want `%pprint` enabled by default, that's just a config setting—and it's _already_ enabled by default, unless you changed something. (At least if you `pip install ipython`, or install the RPM/DEB/port/etc. on any system I've used, it's enabled by default; it's always possible that some platform/distro does things differently.)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ ipython help notebook | grep pprint -A1
--pprint
    Enable auto pretty printing of results.
--
--no-pprint
    Disable auto auto pretty printing of results.


$ ipython help console | grep pprint -A1
--pprint
    Enable auto pretty printing of results.
--
--no-pprint
    Disable auto auto pretty printing of results.
```